# Can anyone identify this notation? $C_{c}(G)$

Tags: group-theory, functions, notation

Apologies if this appears to be a 'low effort' question, but I've been trying to understand this proposition in some lecture notes, and after searching online I cannot understand the following use of notation It isn't defined in the notes, so I was hoping that someone here may have seen it before might be able to let me know what it is.

We have $C_{bu}(G)$ which is defined to be the set of functions on $G$ that are both bounded and uniformly continuous.

Then it states that $C_{c}(G) \subset C_{bu}(G)$ but I'm not sure what $C_{c}(G)$ is. My first thought would be that the $c$ stood for continuous, but then the inclusion wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I agree., if it were the case that $C_c(G)$ were the set of continuous functions on $G$, all bounded uniformly continuous functions are continuous functions but not all continuous functions are bounded uniformly continuous.  It would make sense to me that this may be a typo and the inclusion was meant to be the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C_c(G)$ is the set of all continuous functions with compact support.